# Proxy Authentication Issues

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, proxy, asp.net-4.0

I manage an internal SharePoint portal (Moss 2007) that has webparts, some of which fetch RSS feeds from yahoo news, while others from yahoo finance (daily stock market charts), yet another one with current weather from NOAA. All of these work except yahoo news. The error I get is:

> The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

However, if I run the code locally on my dev box (Win 7) (VS2010) as a web app, the new feed works fine. I understand that this an authentication issue but I can't get any help from our IT security folks.

The difference between the server and my workstation is that I login with a magnetic card and authenticate against the domain. The browser my PC uses goes through a proxy that has some exceptions listed including the SharePoint portal. Bypass proxy for local addresses is checked. The sever itself is locked down from any direct (or via proxy) internet access so the authentication requests have to be coded.

I didn't write this code, but it works fine on one server but will not on my SharePoint server. I have diligently compared setting and found that on a server where it is used as a web widget, it works fine. The web site uses impersonation using a domain account. If I use impersonation in SharePoint, I get logged in with the impersonation account, rather than with my credentials. Are you still with me?

So this code gets the proxy server info fed in but without the any credentials info:

```
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(rssURL);
string[] arrProxy = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyServer"].Split(new Char[] { ',' });
myRequest.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(arrProxy[0], Convert.ToInt32(arrProxy[1]));

WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();

Stream rssStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
XmlDocument rssDoc = new XmlDocument();
rssDoc.Load(rssStream);

XmlNodeList rssItems = rssDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you set the `Credentials` on the request:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```

I guess either with your account, or get the IT guys to create a special "server-webaccess" account.

Comment: There is a such an account in place.

Comment: Here is what the issue was: An other process was using the domain account which was set in the web.config file, except that the string value was in "domain\account" format. So all I had to do was split the string. Your suggestion helped me realize this. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If the proxy only allows request that called by the Browsers you must add user-agent string to your Request For exp: request.UserAgent="Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0; en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101"; If not It will return Error 403 - Forbidden